# Why Resharper deletes my comments?

Tags: c#, resharper

R# 9.0.0 runs in VS 12.0. When it makes "Code Cleanup" with the settings below it removes some comments as follows. Why does it happen?

```
namespace ResharperDeletesMyCommentsWhy
{
    public class MyController
    {
        // This method is not deleted. 
//      public ActionResult MyImportantMethod() { return null; }

        public MyController()
        {
        }

//      public ActionResult MyImportantMethod2()
//      {
//      // this is important method to keep for future use. However R# deletes it. Why?
//          return null;
//      }

    }
}
```

Sample solution at [here](https://github.com/w1ld/resharperDeletesMyCommentsWhy) with the R# and VS settings. Using the "C# Clean up" profile from there as below.

```
<Profile name="C# Clean up">
    <CSRemoveCodeRedundancies> False</CSRemoveCodeRedundancies>
    <CSMakeFieldReadonly> True</CSMakeFieldReadonly>
    <CSUpdateFileHeader> True</CSUpdateFileHeader>
    <CSOptimizeUsings>
        <OptimizeUsings> True</OptimizeUsings>
        <EmbraceInRegion> False</EmbraceInRegion>
        <RegionName>
        </RegionName>
    </CSOptimizeUsings>
    <CSShortenReferences> True</CSShortenReferences>
    <CSharpFormatDocComments> True</CSharpFormatDocComments>
    <CSReorderTypeMembers> True</CSReorderTypeMembers>
    <CSReformatCode> True</CSReformatCode>
</Profile>
```

Also it removes all members when `CSRemoveCodeRedundancies` set. Thanks!

Comment: It's been a while, but under the Clean Up section, isn't there an option for removing comments?

Comment: Look like R# knows commented code is bad... It's just like keeping *"important"* files in the recycle bin ;) On a more serious note, I'd suggest removing *reorder type members*.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Strangely enough it solves the problem. On setting `CSReorderTypeMembers` false. Looks like some old R# settings as I couldn't find it in UI.

Comment: It solves the problem because the comment simply lies here in the middle of class members, and R# doesn't know what to do with it when reordering said members. Should it go at the top? the bottom? stick with the member above/below it? I don't know what solution they chose to implement in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Me and some of my co-workers have also experienced this behaviour. So far, only disabling "Reorder type members" helped.